# How to find the domain of a complex rational function?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the domain of a complex rational function?

E.g.

$$f(z)=\frac{3z-i}{z}$$

I understand that domain means $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for which this is defined, but I don't know what to look for.

---

Perhaps:

Cannot be $z = 0$ because of divizion of zero. But is that all?

---

Are the criteria for "defined" the same as for real rational functions?

Answer (score 4):

$z$ is defined everywhere and so is $3z-i$. The only option for "undefinedness" is the division by zero.

More generally, polynomials are defined everywhere and rational fractions everywhere but at the zeroes of the denominator.

---

General rules:

- $z\pm w$ and $zw$ are defined wherever $z$ and $w$ are defined;
- $\dfrac zw$ is defined where $z$ and $w$ are defined and $w\ne0$;
- $e^z$ is defined wherever $z$ is defined;
- $\log z$ (main branch) is defined wherever $z$ is defined but $z=0$.

This is about all you need to know, all the rest follows.

Comment: Are the "definedness criteria" the same as for real rational functions? Or is there somewhere a list to check for complex functions?

Comment: @mavavilj Complex functions are usually "more defined" than the real counterparts. For example the main branch of the square root is defined in the negatives.

Comment: In Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function#Complex_rational_functions. It says that one must check that there's no division by zero and that there's no common divisor between $P$ and $Q$ of $P/Q$ s.t. one avoids $0/0$. I wonder how to check for the common divisor?

Comment: @mavavilj: no, the wiki defines a rational fraction to be such that there are no common factors. The division rule is exactly as I wrote.

Comment: Even if there was a zero in the numerator and denominator it is still undefined. Unless, you adopt the convention that removable singularities do not count. Some authors do, some don't. For example, $f(z) = \sin(z)/z$. What is the domain ? Some would say nonzero complex numbers, others would say all of $\mathbb{C}$ with the understanding that the power series for $(\sin z)/z = (z-\frac{1}{6}z^3 + \cdots)z = 1-z^2/6+ \cdots$ is entire.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: the link referred to by the OP excludes these situations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust oh, I think your answer is fine. I upvoted it, I merely write what I wrote for the OP. I know you know.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook: no worries :-)